# Can you put a pencil as a bookmark in sifrei Kodesh?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, derech-eretz-manners, orach-chaim, masechet-derech-eretz

BH

Can you put a pencil in sifrei kodesh as a bookmark?

Comment: With very minimal effort, indeed I can.

Comment: It would help to clarify why you think it might be a problem.

Comment: A pen could be an issue (in case the ink explodes) and Shabbat could be an issue (muktzeh gamor) but what is your fear beyond that?

Answer (score 1):

https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Respecting_Holy_Books#Leaving_Objects_in_a_Sefer_or_on_Top

Per this site, you can leave a pencil in as a bookmark only, but not if it’s to guard your Sefer

Comment: What does it mean to "guard your Sefer" ? Guard from what?

Comment: @mbloch Sword attacks. the pen is mightier than the sword.

Comment: @RabbiKaii this is hilarious

Comment: @mbloch hahahahaha idk that’s what it says on the site. Probably means to stop someone from stealing your sefer

Comment: @CuriousYid yes, it means to mark it as "in use" so nobody else takes it in a beis midrash/knesset

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine the only issue would be not hurting the binding if you place the pencil near the spine and close the book on it. (Speaking from sevara as opposed to any halacha I am familiar with).

I would be curious as to where the halachos of kavod for sefarim are written (aside from stacking order) if anyone knows.

Comment: There have been several sefarim written on the topic. You could make it into a question to get recommendations.

Comment: Hi, please see the site guidelines, as this falls under the standard for an answer, and really would be better as a comment.